# Join Tables with sum in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

It is showing Sum(with table name) is not valid. Kindly help:

```
Modws.DisplayDataGrid(dgvClosingBalance, 
                      "Select 
                           Invoice.Customer, Invoice.Sum(Total), 
                           RptTempTable.Sum(INVOICETOTAL), RptTempTable.Sum(CNTOTAL), 
                           RptTempTable.Sum(DEBITTOTAL), RptTempTable.Sum(RECEIPTTOTAL) 
                       From Invoice 
                       inner join RptTempTable on Invoice.Customer = RptTempTable.Customer")
```

Comment: Whats the exact error? what is the data type of the field your trying to SUM

Comment: all is decimal data type..i want to show the sum of all from 2 different tables in a grid view

Comment: There is no `group by` in your statement. Also: which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: im using mysql...so i must add group by customer?

Answer (score 1):

`RptTempTable.Sum(INVOICETOTAL)` should be `Sum(RptTempTable.INVOICETOTAL)`

The same goes for the other calls to `sum()`

The table prefix belongs to the column name not the function call.

---

MySQL will accept this invalid SQL and will return "inderminate" (aka "random") values instead.

To understand the implications of MySQL's "loose" (aka "sloppy") `group by` implementation you might want to read these articles:

- http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/
- http://rpbouman.blogspot.de/2007/05/debunking-group-by-myths.html